# How to find the most fitting X Colors to represent an image?

Tags: image-processing, colors

Let's say we have an Image with [1..n] pixels of the format (r,g,b).

We can now choose X colors also of the format (r,g,b) to generate a second same sized image. 
Each of these X colors will represent n/x freely choosen pixels of our new image.

Now we compute the square deviation from the original image to the new generated image by going over each pixel-pair from [1..n] on both images and summing up their color-differences sqrt(sqr(R1-R2)+sqr(G1-G2)+sqr(B1-B2)).

Now let's assume we distributed all of our X colors so that this sum of square deviations is minimal.

**My question here is**: How to find the perfect X colors so after perfect distribution our square deviation is minimal compared to other color-sets?

If some information is missing or unclear (due to my bad english), please let me know.

Thank You!

PS:
For better understanding I added an example with X = 4. The distribution of colors is nearly optimal, but I'm sure I didn't choose the perfect 4 colors to represent the original image.

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have the reputation for posting an image, so I added the link to it instead
[Before-After example for X=4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CFmX.png)

Comment: Just a side note: proper *color difference* is a lot more complex than the Euclidean Distance in (some) RGB colorspace.

Comment: Are you sure you need each of the colours to represent the same number of pixels (n/x)?

Comment: There is a good write-up and discussion here... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#quantize

Comment: What you are asking is currently unsolved and is NP-hard.  See dhke's answer below.  However, if you do find a solution, tell me so we can win some money together :) http://www.claymath.org/millenium-problems/p-vs-np-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is called [color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization), i.e. given `n` input colors and given at most `m < n` output colors, find the best assignment of color values such that the total color error sum is minimal.

Optimal quantization is [NP hard](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.1133), roughly meaning that there is no known algorithm that works in the general case and does not have to try all possible combinations.

There is --however-- a variety of approximation algorithms, most of which are based on *clustering algorithms*, since the problems is essentially equal to positioning `m` points in a field of `n` points such that the sum of the distance between the (few) `m` points and all the (many) `n` points is minimal.

Note also that using the Euclidean Distance in RGB space is in no way a good measurement to determine [colorimetric color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).